# Fill Dropdown in asp dotnet from Caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a dropdown in asp.net which fills with Agent list. now agent list is 30,000. So I want to keep all the data in cache as we dont need to fill the dropdown again and again from database. How to achieve this by caching. Please guide

Comment: Convert that cache variable to dataset or datatable, and assign to dropdown.Datasource,

Comment: Thank you so much.Please guide me.. I am very new to this caching mechanism..

Comment: see posted answer, and reference link @Saikat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `Cache` varriable, then you have to convert it to `DataTable`,

```
DataTable tblCategories = (DataTable) Cache["Categories"];
```

and , then check, if still Datatable empty, then fetch from database using `LoadCategoryInDropDownList()` function which takes data from databse.

```
if (tblCategories == null) 
    {
      tblCategories = new DataTable();
      tblCategories=objDac.LoadCategoryInDropDownList();
      // It inserts new row in filled datatable.
      //This new row contains static data for user 
      //instruction Text such as" Select the Item"
      DataRow dr=tblCategories.NewRow();
      dr["CategoryID"]=0;
      dr["CategoryName"]="--Select Item--";
      tblCategories.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
      //Cache The DataTable in a Cache Memory for duration of one hour...
      Cache.Insert("Categories", tblCategories, null, 
             DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }
```

then bind dropdown to datatable

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = tblCategories

DropDownList1.DataTextField ="A Descriptive Field from Table";

DropDownList1.DataValueField="A key / Value Field from Table";

DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

You can refer here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10033/A-generic-loading-of-data-in-a-DropDownList-using

Comment: Very good Example. Just tell me which namespace i will use. If i user using System.Web.Caching; It's throwing an error.

Comment: It should use the same, which one you using, using System.Web.Caching; Can you show what is the error?

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Cache.get' 
This is the exact Error. Even cant run my project.

Comment: You have to create Cache["Categories"] first,this is sample, you can create Cache["AgentList"] for your project. Very first time, when you are

Comment: DataTable tblAgentList = (DataTable)Cache["Categories"];
A blue underline in Cache word. If I run the program is throws the error

Comment: just try to follow reference link step by step, thats it

Comment: try this System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache

Answer (score 1):

Do you use particular cache framework?

.Net 4.5 has [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) class you can use.

Example:

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

public Object GetCacheItem(string key) 
{
    return cache[key] as Object; 
}

public void SaveCache(string key, Object value)
{
    cache[key] = value;
}

public void RemoveCacheItem(string key) 
{
    if (cache.Contains(key))
        cache.Remove(key); 
}
```

Once you have your caching setup in a class, you can use it to cache your Agent lists. Then, load it to drop down list.

**WARNING** : Be very careful when using caching. Make sure you clear the cache at the end of certain life cycle. I have seen a case where IIS application pool using all of the memory in a server, so app pool has to be restarted every now and then.

Comment: No I use .Net 4. Please give me any solution.

Comment: .Net 4 also support MemoryCache class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.100).aspx